# IE.Visible = false but window still shows using VBScript

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

So to start off with, I am trying to write this VBScript on my Windows 10 work laptop using IE11. The specific URL I am trying to open in a hidden IE window is housed on my work's server and is built as a SAP Netweaver Portal. I do not have access to SAP in my current position but wanted to write some basic VBScripts to automate pulling employee information.

I have tried using CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""iexplore.exe"" URL", 0) and using CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") with IE.Visible = 0, however neither works. Both methods do work for URLs located on the web but do not work for this specific site. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the procedure code I am using -

```
Dim IE, IEUrl
Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEUrl = "https://portal.companyname.com/abc/portal"

With IE
    .Visible = False
    .Navigate IEUrl
End With
```

When running this code, IE window becomes visible and the active window even though I have set .Visible = False. This only happens with my company's SAP Employee Services site. The code works with any other URL.

Comment: Please show the entire procedure code with proper formatting. Be more specific and show where do and what errors occur?

Comment: I have updated my post with my procedure code and further explanation.

Comment: I'm afraid that it's impossible to make any advice not seeing the HTML content of the web page you are navigating, copied from browser DOM explorer.